# Oracle Query to Fill in Day Gaps Between Grouped Records

Tags: oracle, plsql

Not really sure where to start with the query, but I have two tables, TEST_A and TEST_B.

TEST_B contains a specific date range for a certain ID, while TEST_A contains the date ranges for the ID with a provided ASSIGNMENT value.

Below is the DDL to create and populate the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_A
(
  ID          VARCHAR2(5),
  START_DATE  DATE,
  END_DATE    DATE,
  ASSIGNMENT  VARCHAR2(25)
)
STORAGE    (
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;


CREATE TABLE TEST_B
(
  ID          VARCHAR2(5),
  START_DATE  DATE,
  END_DATE    DATE
)
STORAGE    (
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;
```

And the script to populate the tables:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('A', TO_DATE('01/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('01/31/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot A');

INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('A', TO_DATE('02/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('02/15/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot A');

INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('A', TO_DATE('02/18/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('02/28/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot C');

INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('A', TO_DATE('03/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('03/31/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot D');

INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('B', TO_DATE('08/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('08/31/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot E');

INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('B', TO_DATE('09/15/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('09/30/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot E');

INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('C', TO_DATE('09/15/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('09/30/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot E');


INSERT INTO TEST_B(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
VALUES('A', TO_DATE('01/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/2099', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));

INSERT INTO TEST_B(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
VALUES('B', TO_DATE('08/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/2099', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));

INSERT INTO TEST_B(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
VALUES('C', TO_DATE('01/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/2099', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

From the data, I would need to group those records from TEST_A by the Assignment, and fill in the missing day gaps in between. The records for each ID should also cover the whole start and end date as provided in the table TEST_B. To further explain, the resulting data I need would look like this:

```
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE     ASSIGNMENT
A   01/01/2010  02/15/2010   Lot A
A   02/16/2010  02/17/2010   {NULL}
A   03/01/2010  03/31/2010   Lot D
A   04/01/2010  12/31/2099   {NULL}
B   08/01/2010  08/31/2010   Lot E
B   09/01/2010  09/14/2010   {NULL}
B   09/15/2010  09/30/2010   Lot E
B   10/01/2010  12/31/2099   {NULL}
C   01/01/2010  09/14/2010   {NULL}
C   09/15/2010  09/30/2010   Lot E
C   10/01/2010  12/31/2099   {NULL}
```

Appreciate any help on building the query for this. LAG function comes into mind but I am unsure how to properly write it off. Thanks.

Addition:
If a Stored Procedure will provide flexibility in handling this, then that would still be an accepted solution.

Comment: for a given ID, can a lot repeat later on ? eg on id = A can "lot A" re-appear from apr 2010? or the Lot A dates will always been contiguous?

Comment: There's a possibility that assignments can repeat for every given ID.

Comment: repeating is ok, i mean if we added this complexity: 
INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, ASSIGNMENT)
VALUES('A', TO_DATE('04/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('05/30/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Lot A');
is that valid (so in your final answer, we'd have two ID = A + ASSIGNMENT = Lot A rows.

Comment: Yes that would still be valid.

Comment: ok, I think a pipelined function would solve this just fine (possibly the model clause too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a pipelined function approach (ive added another Lot A (id = A) row in here just to show the result).

```
create type test_typ as object(id varchar2(5),
                               start_date date,
                               end_date date,
                               assignment varchar2(25)
                              );
/
create type test_tab as table of test_typ;
/

create or replace function test_pipe 
return test_tab pipelined is

begin

  for r_row in (select a.id, a.start_date, a.end_date, 
                       a.assignment, 
                       lead(a.start_date, 1) over (partition by a.id order by a.start_date) next_start_date,
                       lead(a.id, 1) over (order by  a.id, a.start_date) next_id,
                       lag(a.id, 1) over (order by  a.id, a.start_date) prior_id,
                       b.start_date min_start, b.end_date max_end
                  from (select id, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date, assignment
                          from (select id, start_date, end_date, assignment, rn, max(rn) over (partition by id order by start_date) r
                                  from (select id, start_date, end_date, assignment, 
                                       case 
                                         when lag(end_date, 1) over (partition by id, assignment order by start_date) = start_date-1 
                                         then null 
                                         else row_number() over (order by start_date) 
                                       end rn
                                  from test_a)
                                 order by id, start_date)
                         group by id, assignment, r) a,
                       test_b b
                 where b.id = a.id
                 order by id, start_date)
  loop
     if ((r_row.prior_id != r_row.id or r_row.prior_id is null) and r_row.start_date > r_row.min_start)
     then
       pipe row(test_typ(r_row.id, r_row.min_start, r_row.start_date-1, null));
     end if;
     pipe row(test_typ(r_row.id, r_row.start_date, r_row.end_date, r_row.assignment));
     if (r_row.next_start_date != r_row.end_date + 1)
     then
       pipe row(test_typ(r_row.id, r_row.end_date + 1, r_row.next_start_date-1, null));
     elsif ((r_row.next_id != r_row.id or r_row.next_id is null) and r_row.end_date < r_row.max_end)
     then
       pipe row(test_typ(r_row.id, r_row.end_date + 1, r_row.max_end, null));
     end if;
  end loop;
end test_pipe;
```

with data:

```
SQL> select * from test_a order by 1, 2;

ID    START_DAT END_DATE  ASSIGNMENT
----- --------- --------- -------------------------
A     01-JAN-10 31-JAN-10 Lot A
A     01-FEB-10 15-FEB-10 Lot A
A     18-FEB-10 28-FEB-10 Lot C
A     01-MAR-10 31-MAR-10 Lot D
A     01-APR-10 30-MAY-10 Lot A
B     01-AUG-10 31-AUG-10 Lot E
B     15-SEP-10 30-SEP-10 Lot E
C     15-SEP-10 30-SEP-10 Lot E


SQL> select *
  2    from table(test_pipe()) b;

ID    START_DAT END_DATE  ASSIGNMENT
----- --------- --------- -------------------------
A     01-JAN-10 15-FEB-10 Lot A
A     16-FEB-10 17-FEB-10
A     18-FEB-10 28-FEB-10 Lot C
A     01-MAR-10 31-MAR-10 Lot D
A     01-APR-10 30-MAY-10 Lot A
A     31-MAY-10 31-DEC-99
B     01-AUG-10 31-AUG-10 Lot E
B     01-SEP-10 14-SEP-10
B     15-SEP-10 30-SEP-10 Lot E
B     01-OCT-10 31-DEC-99
C     01-JAN-10 14-SEP-10
C     15-SEP-10 30-SEP-10 Lot E
C     01-OCT-10 31-DEC-99

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Haven't thought of this initially, but what if there are multiple records on TEST_B table? This would seem to break the query. I will modify the code on insert statement to add this scenario.